# creating a S3 bucket from a browser

Tags: amazon-web-services

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html

Im reading this tutorial for creating a S3 bucket from a browser.

[image]

Could anyone please tell me where Remove public access granted through public ACLs corresponds to?

[image]

also are my settings correct?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the tutorial you linked is to create a public (aka unauthenticated) bucket. The settings in the picture are all for blocking public access, but you want public access. Therefore it is safe to just uncheck all of them.

For example, take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html. They uncheck everything.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if a bucket does not contain any data, there is no harm in making a mistake in configuring the bucket. You can always delete the bucket and try again.